# No able to login in h2-console using inline memory database

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, in-memory-database

I am getting localhost not able to connect after trying to connect through inline db,i am passing correct username password.It was working fine before.Someone else faced this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpZQg.jpg)

Comment: Please share the details mentioned in the properties file.

Comment: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:home
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

#enabling the H2 console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

#persist the data
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:/data/sampledata
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:C:/data/sampledata
server.port=8082

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following configurations in the properties file.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:home
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
server.port=8082
```

Check the application startup logs for h2 enable by `spring.h2.console.enabled`

eg: `H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:home'`

Open the url: http://localhost:8082/h2-console

Verify the jdbc url, and correct it to as per mentioned in properties file and displayed in logs.

```
jdbc:h2:mem:home
```

Test connection.

Comment: Yes,from startup logs i can find.thanks for suggestions